# What's your recommendation regarding a Bitcoin wallet?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet

I'm a novice so go easy on me!!! thanx
I'm writing a freeware open-source program with a donation scheme.
in the end, it will look like [this Github page](https://github.com/BiglySoftware/BiglyBT)

first is PayPal and then multiple cryptocurrencies receive addresses. first on the list that we'll talk about is Bitcoin.

right now I'm downloading Bitcoin core and I hear there are lots of others that install instantly. what's their difference?

on BiglyBt's Readme.md page I see it uses one receive address for all four BCH, BTC, BSG, and BSV coins. can I do that using Bitcoin-core?

basically I want a good Bitcoin Platform and Wallet with high security...

Comment: Hi, welcome to the Bitcoin SE. The other wallets listed on that link are not Bitcoin addresses, thus how to create them is not relevant to this forum. You should refer to the SE forums for those coins for help creating addresses for those coins.

Comment: I was told I can ask any question I have about any cryptocurrency I can post it here. don't you guys read your own SE documentations?

Comment: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic "[your question] is not about … any cryptocurrency or technology that is not applicable to the Bitcoin network and users of the Bitcoin currency" This is not a general cryptocurrency forum -- although I understand why it might look that way!

Comment: I edited the post so that It only concerns bitcoin

Answer (score 1):

I went through a similar problem for generating new bitcoin wallets.
I used the following python libraries:

1. [pycoin](https://github.com/richardkiss/pycoin)
2. [bitcoinlib](https://github.com/1200wd/bitcoinlib)